# Lower case i looks upper case on search results

Tags: bug

On the search result page such as:

https://money.stackexchange.com/search?q=day+trading+margin

Lower case 'i' appears as upper case.  It is lower case, but the font/style makes it appear uppercase such as "bIg margIn".  Anyone else see the same as I do?

Could possibly be a localized font selection issue based on what the browser was best match from my computer, but perhaps its more widespread.

Comment: Indeed. If you zoom in on the page it fixes itself, but with the standard size font it does look a bit like an l.

Comment: Zooming out also fixes the problem.  That is, there are certain sizes where it's a problem and certain sizes where it is not, and those sizes are not contiguous.

Comment: You're right.  I wonder why they use a different font for the question titles in the search results than they do for the question titles on the front page?

Answer (score 2):

This appears to no longer be an issue.  It was probably fixed during the [unified theme rollout](https://money.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2631/10997).